# passing a string value from C function to Objective code in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

I need to use a returned value of a C function in objective C..for Ex:consider a file samplec.h & samplec.c..It contains method definition for display i.e..

```
char *display()
{
    char *b="Hi";
    printf("%s",b);
    return b; 
}
```

This returned value should be called and used in objective C function i.e..in sampleObjC.m  which exist in same project. Can anybody help me with an idea how to do this or any alternatives if exist for passing string value from c file to objective c file in a same project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// sampleObjC.m
#include sampleC.h

- (void)myMethod {
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:display()];
    NSLog(@"%@", string); 
}
```

Comment: Hi Eimantas..Thanks a lot for help..I got what I was trying for :)

Comment: Hi Eimantas ..how can I pass this ... void hseInitialize(void (*receiveCallback)(char *data)); to viewcontroller.m file by using  NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:hseInitialize......].

Comment: wat arguments should I give ??

Comment: You can't pass that function call since function returns void. Not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Ok..Any other method to pass one function & its arguments to another function?